# Vim Insert Sequence with incremental numbers

Tags: vim

On a single line I am looking to turn this:

```
"".format(...)
```

into this:

```
"{0}, {1}, {2}, ..... {n}".format(...)
```

where `n` is the number of elements I wish to repeate. Without the need to manually insert each argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this way is ok for you:

```
"I(cursor here)
".format(...)
```

execute command:

```
:r! seq -s, -f "{\%g}" 0 20
```

then join (`J`) the 3 lines. 20 is `n` in your case.

or `"I".format(...)`

to insert mode, `ctrl-R` then type `=system("seq -s, -f '{%g}' 0 20")`

Answer (score 2):

With the cursor between the empty double quotes, I would do (for `n` = 5):

```
i<C-R>=join(map(range(5), 'printf("{%d}", v:val)'), ', ')<CR>
```

Some *vimgolf* enthusiasts can probably condense this further. But I would probably either write a mapping for it (if the need occurs so frequently), or do it manually like this:

```
5i{0}, <Esc>^f0;<C-A>;2<C-A>;3<C-A>;4<C-A>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a macro, like:

```
0a{0}, <esc>lqqyF{f"PB<C-a>;q
```

Then just use whatever n-1 is with `@q`. E.g. `4@qXX` would give:

```
"{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}".format(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "seq" command in Windows, so I prefer this:

```
:call append(".", map(range(6), '"{".v:val."},"'))
```

and then join these lines use '6J'.